# casperjsで遅延ロード設定された画像を含む全キャプチャを取得

Tags: casperjs

**概要**
caspesjsで、http://lohaco.jp/event/foodsale/のサイトような、
画面をスクロールしないと表示されない画像もすべて画面キャプチャを取得したいです。
有識者の方がいましたらアドバイスお願いいいたします。

**詳細**
スクロールをするよう設定すればよいかと思いcasper.scrollToBottom()を試しましたがうまくスクロールできでいないようでした。
また、casper.wait()で時間をおいて取得しようとしてもうまくいきませんでした。
全画面の取得はできますが、画像が表示されません。
キャプチャ取得部分のソースは以下のように記載しています。

```
this.start('http://lohaco.jp/event/foodsale/',function(){
    this.evaluate(function() {
       document.body.bgColor = 'white';
    });
});

this.then(function() {
        this.scrollToBottom();
        this.wait(1000,function() {
                           this.capture('capture.png');
                         });
});
```